# Wordpress - get all posts from multiple parent categories?

Tags: wordpress

let's say I have categories structure like this:

```
food        (id = 1)
  chicken   (id = 2)
  beef      (id = 3)

beverage     (id = 11)
  soft-drink (id = 12)
  juice      (id = 13)

branch
  ... // not important
```

I want to show all posts from `food` and `beverage`, so I do this:

```
$args = array('category__in' => array(1, 11) );
get_posts( $args );
```

That code doesn't work because I only tick the child category.

Of course I can do `array(1, 2, 3, 11, 12, 13)` but it's not DRY.

Is there a good way to **get all posts using the parent category's ID**?

Thanks

[My Code based on answer below]

```
$args = array(
  'category' => implode(",", array(1, 11) )
);
get_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `cat` instead of `category__in`, `category__in` will not get the categories children. You can get this info [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters):

Check this:

> Display posts that have this category (and any children of that category), using category id:
>   $query = new WP_Query( 'cat=1,11' );

That code brings any children of that category but this:

> Display posts that have this category (not children of that category), using category id:
>   $query = new WP_Query( 'category__in=1,11' );

is getting only posts from the category with that id.

Now to pass multiple category ids to cat you can build a string with [php implode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) if you have the ids as array.

you can also check this example:

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
$args = array(
   'cat' => 1,
   'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
   'post__not_in' => $sticky,
   'paged' => $paged
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I haven't tested to see if you can pass an array of cat ids like `'cat'=>array(1,11)` but you can test it and see if it works.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot, I always thought that the query accepts `id` in array format. It's actually just a comma-separated string.